# How to get information from android device if there is a calendar event update?

Tags: android, calendar

From developer prospective...
How can I get to know if a calendar event from an android device is added/edited/deleted by the user. I need to do some operations if there is any update on calendar events.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going to assume you are talking about the Google Calendar app and not the Corporate Calendar app.

I don't believe that the Google Calendar app provides an API for this (or any API at all), and unless it does you won't be able to get any sort of event from it.  You would have to create your own app that logs in to the Google account and periodically checks the calendar itself.

Comment: Yes. That can be done and I have implemented the same in my code. But is there any broadcast receiver or observers which will let us know if there is any calendar event update.